# Snap.svg - How to change a polyline to another svg object

Tags: svg, snap.svg

So SVG and expecially Snap.svg is very new to me an I am stuck on trying to get my svg object to animate along a defined path.

I have setup a fiddle showing what I have been able to accomplish so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/k1L0g5j2/1/

```
// ---------
//  SVG C
// ---------

var snapC = Snap("#svgC");

// SVG C - "Squiggly" Path
var myPathC = snapC.path("M1462,170c0,0,42,282-236,290s-270-68-506,60s-273.7,70.4-466-160C32,94-232,170-240,358c0,420.4,498-272,598-68").attr({
    fill: "none"
});

// SVG C - Draw Path
var lenC = myPathC.getTotalLength();

// SVG C - Triangle (As Polyline)
var Triangle = snapC.polyline("0,30 15,0 30,30");
Triangle.attr({
    id: "plane",
    fill: "#fff"
});

var triangleGroup = snapC.g(Triangle); // Group polyline

setTimeout(function () {
    Snap.animate(0, lenC, function (value) {
        movePoint = myPathC.getPointAtLength(value);
        triangleGroup.transform('t' + parseInt(movePoint.x) + ',' + parseInt(movePoint.y - 15) + 'r' + (movePoint.alpha - 90));
    }, 4500, mina.easeinout);
});
```

But I need to change this triangle to be another SVG object (moth.svg). I can't figure out how this is done.

Comment: Instead of the polyline func, use Snap.load http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.load make sure you load the animation after the callback has run or from within it, an example at http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate.html Note, you may need to fiddle with the svg loaded in. Because the animated draw is rotating a triangle around a point, you need to think what point that is, and if some adjustment of the svg offset is needed if your svg isn't centralised.

Comment: Thanks Ian,

However, I am still running into problems getting this to work. I have updated a new jsfiddle with where I ended up: http://jsfiddle.net/k1L0g5j2/2/

So as you can see, nothing is working at all anymore.

Comment: There's a couple of related issues here. It can't load Moth.svg, it doesn't know where it is, so it would need an absolute URL for the script to reference. Second issue is, even if it can find it, the load function takes a callback, and things are only run from the callback function. Here is an example http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate.html note you would need to have the URL as an absolute URL if the file isn't local.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the follow up. However, I am still a bit unsure what you mean when you mention that it takes a "callback" – please forgive my ignorance. I updated the JSFiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/k1L0g5j2/4/

This time using a absolute path to a random svg image that I found. Any way you can expand on what you mean when you say it needs a callback?

Comment: Loading is asynchronous. This means that while some data is loading, javascript carries on running, the order isn't guaranteed. Lets say the file takes 10 secs to load. A callback is a function that runs on completion of some event (like data load). So you have to make sure any variable assignements dependant on the load only happen after the data has finished loading. So load takes 2 arguments, the file to load, and then the function to call once its finished loading. That function itself takes a parameter of the loaded fragment. See   http://jsfiddle.net/k1L0g5j2/7/ which I've amended.

Comment: #bestanswerever – Thanks so much! Makes complete sense.